# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Can't locate an element by this strategy: Locator map:

Tags: appium, appium-android

Element is visible but still Appium is not tapping over any element available in that screen. Whereas I can able to access the elements in previous screen.

I've tried by all possible means

1. driver.findElementById("AddNewFarmer").click();
2. And using pageobjects too. 
   Also tried with xpath, but still can't able to access the element.

## I tried with both Appium version 1.8 and 1.10. Please help me on this

**Server log:**

```
[HTTP] {"using":"id","value":"AddNewFarmer"}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElements() with args: ["id","AddNewFarmer","c5acec26-3a1f-495a-a9c2-574ef2a17a69"]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"AddNewFarmer","context":"","multiple":true}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"AddNewFarmer","context":"","multiple":true}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'AddNewFarmer' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: true
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=com.olam.digital.ofispreprod:id/AddNewFarmer]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=com.olam.digital.ofispreprod:id/AddNewFarmer]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.olam.digital.ofispreprod:id/AddNewFarmer]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=android:id/AddNewFarmer]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=android:id/AddNewFarmer]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=android:id/AddNewFarmer]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=AddNewFarmer]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=AddNewFarmer]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
```

=====================================================

**Error log:**

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Can't locate an element by
>   this strategy: Locator map: 
>   - native content: "By.id: AddNewFarmer" 
>   - html content: "by id or name "addNewFarmer"" For documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: '2.53.1', revision:
>   'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30
>   19:26:09' System info: host: 'INCHN-LAP960', ip: '10.190.4.15',
>   os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_172' Driver info: driver.version: unknown    at
>   io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.findElement(AppiumElementLocator.java:110)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.interceptors.InterceptorOfASingleElement.intercept(InterceptorOfASingleElement.java:57)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c0b591f0.toString()
>     at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)   at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.toString(ExpectedConditions.java:293)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:257)
>     at
>   com.olamnet.OFIS.utilities.ActionItems.waitAction(ActionItems.java:68)
>     at
>   com.olamnet.OFIS.commonActions.LoginEnumerator.loginWithValidEnumeratorId(LoginEnumerator.java:60)
>     at
>   com.olamnet.OFIS.stepDefinition.LoginEnumeratorStep.enter_a_valid_Enumerator_ID_and_verify(LoginEnumeratorStep.java:31)
>     at ?.Then Enter a valid Enumerator ID and
>   verify(EnumeratorLogin.feature:13)

Comment: How are you defining the appiumDriver? How are you implementing page object model? Initializing appiumDriver  as static may solve your problem.

Comment: @SubanDhyako I'm not using AppiumDriver. I'm using AndroidDriver as static. Do I need to change this? Thanks for your instant reply

Comment: can you show your code? you can try using AppiumDriver<MobileElement>.

Comment: @SubanDhyako Same piece of code is working fine for real device. But not working for emulators.

Comment: Try using exciplicit wait to the second screen where you are not able to intearact with element. Sometime the screen element may not be loaded properly while the appium tries to interact with element.

Comment: @SubanDhyako Yeah I used explicit wait too. But it didn't worked. Reason is that app is developed to work in offline state. So device for which local db is available it's working. And that is the reason it works for real device and not for emulator. Thanks for your great instant inputs!